# Trying to understand the difference between a regular clocked flip flop and a falling edge triggered one

Tags: flipflop

I tried simulating both:

[Falling edge triggered one](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.634267539816555+50+5+50%0A151+432+144+528+144+0+2+5+5%0A151+432+256+528+256+0+2+0+5%0Aw+432+224+432+240+0%0Aw+432+160+432+176+0%0Aw+528+224+528+256+0%0Aw+528+224+432+176+0%0Aw+528+144+528+176+0%0Aw+528+176+432+224+0%0AM+560+144+672+144+0+2.5%0AM+592+256+640+256+0+2.5%0Ax+652+141+670+144+4+24+Q%0Ax+627+256+645+259+6+24+Q%0Ax+272+99+284+102+4+24+J%0AR+96+176+-112+176+1+2+100+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0AL+320+272+256+272+0+1+false+5+0%0Ax+263+247+279+250+4+24+K%0AL+320+128+256+128+0+1+false+5+0%0Ax+-216+161+-156+164+4+14+click%5Cshere%0Aw+560+144+560+336+0%0Aw+560+336+320+336+0%0Aw+320+336+320+288+0%0Aw+592+256+592+80+0%0Aw+592+80+320+80+0%0Aw+320+80+320+112+0%0Aw+320+144+320+192+0%0Aw+320+256+320+192+0%0A151+320+128+432+128+0+3+5+5%0A151+320+272+432+272+0+3+5+5%0Aw+560+144+528+144+0%0Aw+592+256+528+256+0%0A153+192+192+320+192+0+2+0+5%0AI+16+208+80+208+0+0.5+5%0AI+80+208+192+208+0+0.5+5%0AI+-48+208+16+208+0+0.5+5%0Aw+-48+208+-48+176+0%0Aw+96+176+-48+176+0%0Aw+96+176+192+176+0%0Ao+16+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+16+3+J%0Ao+14+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+14+3+K%0Ao+8+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+1+Q%0Ao+13+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+2+13+3+clk%0A)

[Regular clocked JK flip flop](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.634267539816555%2050%205%2050%0A151%20432%20144%20528%20144%200%202%205%205%0A151%20432%20256%20528%20256%200%202%200%205%0Aw%20432%20224%20432%20240%200%0Aw%20432%20160%20432%20176%200%0Aw%20528%20224%20528%20256%200%0Aw%20528%20224%20432%20176%200%0Aw%20528%20144%20528%20176%200%0Aw%20528%20176%20432%20224%200%0A151%20320%20128%20432%20128%200%203%205%205%0A151%20320%20272%20432%20272%200%203%205%205%0AM%20528%20144%20592%20144%200%202.5%0AM%20528%20256%20592%20256%200%202.5%0Ax%20563%20123%20581%20126%204%2024%20Q%0Ax%20585%20235%20603%20238%206%2024%20Q%0Ax%2030%2047%2042%2050%204%2024%20J%0AL%2032%20272%2032%20240%200%201%20false%205%200%0Ax%204%20223%2020%20226%204%2024%20K%0AL%2032%20112%2032%2080%200%201%20false%205%200%0Aw%20560%20144%20560%20320%200%0Aw%20560%20320%20320%20320%200%0Aw%20320%20320%20320%20288%200%0Aw%20544%20256%20544%2080%200%0Aw%20544%2080%20320%2080%200%0Aw%20320%2080%20320%20112%200%0Aw%20560%20144%20528%20144%200%0Aw%20544%20256%20528%20256%200%0Aw%2032%20272%20320%20272%200%0Aw%20320%20128%2032%20128%200%0Aw%2032%20128%2032%20112%200%0AR%20112%20176%2080%20176%201%202%20100%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20112%20176%20112%20144%200%0Aw%20112%20144%20320%20144%200%0Aw%20112%20176%20112%20240%200%0Aw%20112%20240%20112%20256%200%0Aw%20112%20256%20320%20256%200%0Ax%2060%20184%2089%20187%204%2024%20clk%0Ao%2017%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2017%203%20J%0Ao%2015%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2015%203%20K%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%20Q%0A)

I think there is something wrong with them because when both inputs are high they look like they are having a seizure rather than toggling.

I thought I understood it, I've tinkered with it, I've looked at the scopes but at this point I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make latches this way and bad ones too that oscillate with negative feedback.  Notice the blur of oscillations. when both JK =1.

[image]

True Flip Flops MUST HAVE  2 latches to make the output edge triggered so that the 2nd stage input conditions cannot change on the clock edge.
[image]
They are actually implemented in CMOS  Transmission gates as well.

Comment: But am I not suppose to use something like this when I want to make a falling edge triggered flip flop? https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/04191.png

Comment: What part of that is an invalid FF do you misunderstand?

Comment: I believe you. I'm just surprised because I've seen my professor do this and accept projects that were done like this.